# Complementing user stats

Tags: discussion

Could *positive response*, meaning the number of okayed or upvoted answers be made a percentage and complement the Q&A user stats? The same goes for upvoted questions. For example: Positive response: 40.2%, 25%. The first figure is  A's, the other is Q's. Badges only count Q&A upvotes and that starting with at least 10.

Note: reputation includes downvotes whereas *positive response* gives the percentage of only **good** answers and questions.

Comment: (not my downvote) - Can you tell us what problem this would solve?

Comment: Like people would be encouraged to stay? Even **one** upvoted zero score answer means 100% positive response. Isn't it great? And such an extra summary would've given users a better idea of their achievements. Now you need to go through all Q's &A's which may be time consuming if there are hundreds of them.

Comment: But what does that achieve that reputation doesn't already?

Comment: Saves time, that's all. A summary at a glance.

Comment: Besides, reputation includes downvotes whereas positive response gives the percentage of only **good** answers and questions.

Comment: Bounty earned counts as a positive response either.

Comment: eh, i actually kinda like this idea. Not every change to the system has to be "solving a problem," it just needs to not *cause* a problem. I think showing ratios could be good reinforcement for people to not post content that would push their ratios down. If you've got 10k rep and your ratio is 5%.... you've got some cleaning up to do. I'd suggest sticking to a more quantifiable stat, like net votes per post.

Comment: @Kevin B: No need to delete posts as often an upvote or accept comes much later. It's just to remind people how many downvoted and dead, i.e. zero score unaccepted posts they have. Just to keep quality.

Comment: Anti-related: [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951)

Answer (score 3):

> Even *one* upvoted zero score answer means 100% positive response. Isn't it great?

No, it isn't. Making a user who has made one post that got a single pity upvote seem like a more able contributor than someone who has made thousands of posts with an average of 10 upvotes per-post is... well, it kind of speaks for itself. Mediocrity is not something we want to encourage.

Reputation may not be a perfect system, but it's a lot better at showing who is posting content that is genuinely *valued* by the community and who has yet to do so. We don't want to hand out "participation awards"; we want this stuff to mean something.

And your "positive response" doesn't mean anything. It doesn't mean anything about the content a user posts. It biases towards people with fewer contributions than those with more. It doesn't properly discourage negative contributions, since those don't get properly recorded. It's just a bad system if you care about quality.

We don't want to encourage people to stay. We want to encourage *skilled users* to stay.